# How do you perform a deep copy on a doubly-linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm having a hard time getting around the pointers.  I can imagine someone here can make conceptualizing the copy constructor much more intuitive.  I understand that you can't simply assign pointers to each other (shallow copy), but I'm having a hard time actually copying the objects.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
class LList {
    /* stuff */

    private:
        struct node {
            node   *next;
            node   *prev;
            int    *o;
        };

        node   *first; // The pointer to the first node (NULL if none)
        node   *last;  // The pointer to the last node (NULL if none)
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just think of it as creating a new list and adding copies of your original items to it.

Comment: What have you tried? It would be much easier to answer, if you had your current code included, and question was based on that.

Comment: And it makes a huge difference if the items in your list are pointers. Add at least the data structure and the insertion of data to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are writing the copy constructor, `X(const T& other)`, for an object, `X`, that contains a dynamically allocated `T* p` (probably a `Node*` in your case), you will likely end up writing a line like this:

```
p = new T(*other.p);
```

This creates a copy of the object being pointed to by the object you're copying, giving you a deep copy of that object. In your case, this would end up in a recursive deep-copying of the list.

Comment: @AshRj Made an edit to clear that up. `other` is the object you're copying and `p` is the thing it owns that you want to deep-copy from it.

Comment: Now, what do you mean by recursive deep copy ?

Comment: @AshRj Copying the object `other.p` will invoke `p`'s copy constructor/assignment which can then also do a deep copy of whatever `other.p` owns. If, as in this case, a `node` has a pointer to another `node` which has a pointer to another `node` (and so on), when the first `node` is copied, it will copy the `node` it points to, which will then copy the `node` that *it* points to, etc, etc. This causes a recursive deep copy. You end up with a whole list of `node`s that are all copies of the original list.

Comment: How would you handle the next / prev pointer inside the copy constructor ? I get that this will allocate and copy data of each node to a new node but what about the linking.

Comment: @AshRj The `node` copy constructor would contain something along the lines of `next = new node(*other.next); prev = new node(*other.prev); o = new int(*other.o);`. Not that advocate using raw pointers or dynamically allocating single `int`s, but in this example, that's how it would work.

Comment: X| I think i will better understand this when i implement it. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @AshRj Oh sorry, I made a mistake. `prev` shouldn't also be copied, otherwise you'd have duplicate nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a deep copy of a linked list is equivalent to creating a new linked list with the same data values.

So, you could

- Traverse through your current list
- Extracting the information from each node
- Pass it to a new node (essentially copying everything other than the list pointers)
- Add that to the new list (which is the deep copy).

In your case, you need to deference o, extract the data, allocate a new block, assign the data and then add that to the new node.

Comment: What if the information in the list is an int pointer, for example; do we have to deference first?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this might express part of the idea you're getting at. I'd try to use `std::list` instead though :) **You should add a copy assignment operator and a destructor that allocates/deallocates appropriately as well**. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

```
template<typename T>
struct ListNode {
    ListNode *next, *prev;
    T value;

    ListNode(const T &val): value(val), next(0), prev(0) {}

    // copy constructor
    ListNode(const ListNode &other): value(other.value) {
        if(other.next)
           append(new ListNode(*other.next));
    }

    void append(ListNode &n) {
        next = &n; n.prev = this;
    }
};
```

If your `value` is a pointer, then you'll want to copy that in the same way the `next` pointer member is copied above, i.e.:

```
    // copy constructor
    ListNode(const ListNode &other): value(new T(*other.value)) {
        if(other.next)
           append(new ListNode(*other.next));
    }
```

So for your example list above, you might try something like this:

```
class LList {
    LList(): first(0), last(0) {}

    // copy constructor
    LList(const LList &other):
        first(0),
        last(0)
    {
        if(other.first) {
          first = new node(*other.first);
          // find last item
          last = first;
          while(last->next) last = last->next;
        }
    }

    ~LList() {
       if(first) delete first;
    }

    // TODO: copy assignment operator

private:
    struct node {
        node(int val): next(0), prev(0), o(new int(val)) {}
        // copy constructor
        node(const node &other): next(0), prev(0), o(*other.o)
        {
            if(other.next) {
               next = new node(*other.next);
               next->prev = this;
            }   
        }

        ~node() {
          delete o;
          if(next) delete next;
        }
        // TODO: copy assignment operator

        node   *next;
        node   *prev;
        int    *o;
    };

    node   *first; // The pointer to the first node (NULL if none)
    node   *last;  // The pointer to the last node (NULL if none)
};
```

Untested but that's the idea...constructors work recursively by operating on the next item. The 'TODO' items are important, as explained by the link. You might also want to look into smart pointers - they remove the need to remember to delete things, improve exception safety and are generally a much safer option than raw pointers.

Comment: Should the if(other.next) be a while(other.next)?

Comment: @Bob John - no, because it's recursive. Nodes past 'next' will be created in the constructor of the next node, and so on.

Comment: So how can I use this to write a copy constructor for the class above, Llist(const Llist &construct);?